# Execute C# code directly from Otter script

Tags: c#, otter-script

I've been working with Otter script for a bit now, and I'd like to execute C# code directly from one of my plans. I know I can execute PowerShell code directly using `PSExec`, but is there an equivalent for C# like `CSExec` or similar?

Here is the code I would like to run:

```
if (Directory.Exists($Path))
  LonUtil.SendEmail("Path exists!");
else
  LonUtil.SendEmail("Path does not exist.", false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new type in Powershell and call the code directly from there using `PSExec`:

```
$source = @"
public class MyCode
{
    public void Action(string path) 
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(path);
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source
$MyCode = New-Object MyCode
$MyCode.Action("Write this to the console!")
```

---

Alternatvely, compile that c# code into an assembly, say `MyApplication.exe`, and then write a powershell script which executes the program:

```
$path = "the/required/path"
& MyApplication.exe $path
```

Then use `PSExec` from Otter Script to run the above bit of Powershell

Comment: Eh, compiling to an EXE might be overkill. A more direct equivalent would be something like [scriptcs](http://scriptcs.net/).

Comment: @mason I added an alternate solution at the top

Comment: My other option was to create an exe for it and use `Exec` instead of custom PowerShell, but the `Add-Type` command will work for now, thanks!